# Display or hide drawer with onClick

Tags: javascript

The following is my code for my "drawer" to be display or hidden on the basis whether it has been clicked or not. I want to make this better as personally its messy. Any tips?

```
//Checks if the page loaded is of specific type    
if(window.location.href.indexOf("home.php") > -1) {
      //Handles the displaying of the side bar on the home page.
      var button = document.getElementById('navIcon');
      button.onclick = function() {
          var div = document.getElementById('drawer');
          if (div.style.display !== 'block') {
              div.style.display = 'block';
              //If the document is over 900px. Readjusts the grid, Otherwise overlay
              if(document.body.clientWidth > 900) {
                  document.getElementById('resGrid').style.width = 'calc(100% - 240px)';
              }
          }
          else {
              div.style.display = 'none';
              document.getElementById('resGrid').style.width = '100%';
          }
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
button.onclick = function() {
```

Use `addEventListener` instead. That way, you can add as many handlers as you want without replacing any previous ones assigned.

```
if (div.style.display !== 'block') {
```

Instead of using inline CSS, put them in stylesheets and define the styles in classes. Then have JS assign/remove classes instead to apply/remove. The problem is that 1) You have CSS in your JS and 2) inline CSS have very high specificity. The only way to override them is to replace the inline style value, or use `!important` on the stylesheet.

```
if(document.body.clientWidth > 900) {
```

If you also use CSS, this can easily be remedied by media queries.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("home.php") > -1) {
```

You probably want to use a more robust routing library like Page.js to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Joseph the Dreamer already provided a great review, so I don't have much to say.

---

### Reduce DOM searching calls

You are calling `document.getElementById` quite a few times in this code. While it is a very helpful method, it can be expensive and you want to avoid using it more than you have to.

To speed up this code, move the creations of variables `div` out of the function, along with the call for the `'resGrid'` element. Here's what I mean:

```
var button = document.getElementById('navIcon');
var div = document.getElementById('drawer');
var resGrid = document.getElementById('resGrid');

button.onclick = function() {
```

This will reduce the amount of `document.getElementById` calls that are made each time this event is set off, thus speeding up your code.

---

### Use a boolean state

Right now, to determine if you set the element's display to `block` or not, you do a string comparison with the element's current display value.

A faster solution would be to have a single boolean variable that tells the state of the element. For example, you could call it this:

```
var isBlock = true; // or false, if it starts off not 'block'
```

Then, instead of checking with a string, you check with this variable (and change it if necessary), which will also speed up your code.